# Swift: Black/ grey border on SearchBar not going away until clicked

Tags: ios, swift, border, uisearchbar

Using Swift 3 and testing on my device, I've tried several code that should remove the black/grey border but it's not being removed. The weird thing is the border is there but once I click on the searchBar ready to type, the border isn't there anymore until the view is loaded again. So the border is just showing until I click the searchBar.

This is my code:

```
// Coloring TableView
myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
myTableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.black
myTableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.black

// Search Bar
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

// Coloring SearchBar Cancel button
let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.normal)

// Scope: Selected text
let titleTextAttributesSelected = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributesSelected, for: .selected)

// Scope: Normal text
let titleTextAttributesNormal = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributesNormal, for: .normal)

// Coloring Scope Bar
UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white

// Search Bar
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
myTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

// Scope Bar
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Released", "Unreleased", "Open Beta"]
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

// SEARCH BAR: Filtering Content
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {

    filteredFollowedArray = followedArray.filter { Blog in

        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (Blog.blogType == scope)

        return categoryMatch && (Blog.blogName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
    }

    filteredBlogArray = blogArray.filter { Blog in

        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (Blog.blogType == scope)

        return categoryMatch && (Blog.blogName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()
}

// SEARCH BAR: Updating Results
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {}

// SEARCH BAR: Scope
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {

    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
}

// SEARCH BAR: Updating Scope
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]

    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
}

// Deallocating Search Bar
deinit{
    if let superView = searchController.view.superview {
        superView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

This is how the searchBar looks when the view is first loaded, the line on the top is grey (I don't why here the grey looks so faded, you can't see it but a very thin line of grey is there):

[image: pic1]

and after you click the searchBar, the line turns black:

[image: pic2]

And this happens when I add this code which was referred to me:

```
// Search Bar Border
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

[image: pic3]

and this is after I click on the searchBar with that code, and how it's supposed to look. No border:

[image: pic4]

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking this behavior in the small sized simulator only? The black line in your second screen shot doesn't look connected to your search bar in the first screenshot. It looks like the bottom of the status bar instead. Sometimes simulator can't display thin lines properly. I would increase the simulator size to the biggest or better yet, test it on a phone.

Comment: this is all on my device, iPhone 6s